# How to add multiple files to ZipArchive in O(n) time

Tags: php, optimization, php-ziparchive

I am offering a means of downloading multiple photos as a single archive file.

TAR format works fine, but most people don't have anything that can open TAR files on their device, then complain that it doesn't work.

ZIP format is unnecessary (since photos are already compressed), but is one that most people will be able to open.

The built-in PHP class [`ZipArchive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) appears to only have a method `addFile` to add one file at a time.  It seems that this involves decompression and recompression of the entire archive, with the effect that the more files you add, the slower it gets - i.e. it runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time to add n files.  The effect of that becomes catastrophic beyond about 30-40 hi-res photos.

Have I missed something about `ZipArchive`?  Or is this a shortcoming in the class that should be put forward as a feature request?

Are there alternatives to achieve the goal of a quick-to-produce archive format that most people will be able to open without installing additional software?

Comment: Are you calling `open()` and `close()` each time through the loop? Don't do that. Open it once, add all the files, then close it.

Comment: Have you actually tried with ZipArchive code? If it is time consuming, given the end users a link to go through the high res image gallery.

Comment: "It seems that this involves decompression and recompression of the entire archive" - does it? Can you share some code that shows this behaviour?

Comment: Zip entries are not necessarily compressed. You can use the `CM_STORE` compression method to disable compression (as shown [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setcompressionname.php)). It will be much faster.

Comment: @Barmar, No I'm not closing and re-opening unless the adding of files needs to be batched to avoid server timeouts - maybe that's where the issue comes in: the second batch takes a lot longer than the first, etc.

Comment: @nice_dev, I'm offering facility to download files in bulk, rather than individually.

Comment: @NicoHaase, If the archive is closed and re-opened, that may require decompression and recompression, certainly if ZIP compresses beyond file beyond file boundaries, though was speculating somewhat.

Comment: @Olivier, Thanks, definitely worth look at option flags available.

Comment: It may be that the format of a ZIP file is designed to start a fresh compression when _adding_ more stuff.  (This would avoid the feared de/recompression.)

Comment: Who closed this?  And why is there no 'paper trail' for the closure?  I won't delete it, but due to your attitude and approach, I have lost interest in helping others on this site, so will not be adding any more information either.  I am disappointed.

Comment: There is paper trail. If you can't see it, it might be because you don't have yet the required reputation score. And I'm sorry you're disappointed, but I spent quite time preparing and running the benchmark and I think the information is useful even if my runs are not very scientific.

Comment: If you have any additional questions about this problem, please edit your post to contain all details. Did you even check whether there is any difference between calling `close()` within the loop (after adding each individual file) or not? "The effect of that becomes catastrophic" - please share the code involved, and a clear description of this "catastrophic" effect. How long does it actually take? How large are these images?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks and I appreciated that.  It shows that there's a missing piece of the puzzle I hadn't considered, which is that I'm batching the additions to avoid timeouts.

Comment: @NicoHaase I am busy on another project at the moment and have not had time to revisit this in a testing sense.  It might be typically 100-200 images of about 10Mb each.  I will add some pseudo-code to the question.

Comment: For a 2GB archive, I'd absolutely consider invoking `zip` command [from PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php), it isn't a bad or unusual approach.

Answer (score 4):

It would be a pretty flawed design if that was the case, but you never know, so let's test it.

First, let's prepare some 50 MB files to use during the rest of the benchmarks:

```
define('FILE_COUNT', 100);
mkdir(__DIR__ . '/data');
for ($i =0; $i < FILE_COUNT; $i++) {
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/data/file-$i.txt", str_repeat('x', 52_428_800));
}
```

Now, let's create some ZIP archives with increasing numbers of files:

```
define('FILE_COUNT', 1); // <-------- We'll be increasing this

$t0 = microtime(true);

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open(__DIR__ . '/zip-test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
for ($i = 0; $i < FILE_COUNT; $i++ ){
    $zip->addFile(__DIR__ . "/data/file-$i.txt");
}
echo "Files added: {$zip->numFiles}\n";
echo "Status: {$zip->status}\n";
$zip->close();

$time = microtime(true) - $t0;
echo "Total time: " . number_format($time, 3) . " seconds\n";
echo "Average time: " . number_format($time / FILE_COUNT, 3) . " seconds/file\n";
echo "Max RAM used: " . number_format(memory_get_peak_usage(real_usage: true)) . " bytes\n";
```

In my current computer (Windows 10 desktop, PHP/8.1.15 64-bit):

```
Files added: 1
Status: 0
Total time: 0.505 seconds
Average time: 0.505 seconds/file
Max RAM used: 2,097,152 bytes
```

```
Files added: 10
Status: 0
Total time: 4.854 seconds
Average time: 0.485 seconds/file
Max RAM used: 2,097,152 bytes
```

```
Files added: 100
Status: 0
Total time: 48.428 seconds
Average time: 0.484 seconds/file
Max RAM used: 2,097,152 bytes
```

So... This is of course not a scientific benchmark, just a quick test to figure out the overall situation. And the conclusion is that it appears to be linear and it definitively does not compress and uncompress the entire archive every time. In fact, the big delay happens in `$zip->close()`.

Then I ran some test disabling compression entirely:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < FILE_COUNT; $i++ ){
    $zip->addFile(__DIR__ . "/data/file-$i.txt");
    $zip->setCompressionName(__DIR__ . "/data/file-$i.txt", ZipArchive::CM_STORE);
}
```

Much faster indeed:

```
Files added: 100
Status: 0
Total time: 19.541 seconds
Average time: 0.195 seconds/file
Max RAM used: 2,097,152 bytes
```

Last but not least, an earlier version of this informal benchmark used `->addFromString()` without too much thought and I found a consistent increase in RAM usage as I added more files.

Conclusions:

- Quick testing suggest it's O(n).
- Disable compression if your files are already compressed.
- Let ZipArchive load your files from disk whenever possible.

Comment: *"your concern should be RAM"* If you use `addFile()` instead of `addFromString()`, I don't think so.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect that. I might update the test code if I have time later.

Comment: Thanks, I will test this.  My server is still on PHP 7.3 (because some sites are not compatible with later versions - they are using older versions of WordPress, which can't be updated because the plugins they use have been discontinued).  What PHP version were you using?  Could be an issue that has been fixed in more recent PHP versions (but again, just speculating).

Comment: I've tested in 8.2 (Linux) and 8.1 (Windows). I don't think the Zip extension has been revamped since it was created, if you found some issue it might have been due to some misuse of it.

Comment: Somebody closed this question, without any explanation beyond a standard message, or saying who they were.  So I won't be posting the results of my tests.

Comment: 49 seconds is too long, so it has to be broken up - then fails catastrophically.

Comment: @Jake Slow? Maybe. But I don't think it's slow because PHP is recompressing the entire archive every time you add a new file, which was your question. You're creating a very large archive (what's the size of the resulting file that contains your 40 high-res pictures?) with an interpreted language. If you need high performance, invoke an external zip tool written in C. Also, my average performing computer from year 2019 was able to create a 5 GB zip file in less than 20 seconds, while running through the IDE, so you may have a bottleneck of some kind.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Probably not such much a bottleneck as a consequence of running on shared hosting, where you only get a fraction of the CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the comments in the [ZipArchive::addFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php) manual, it looks like the file is not actually added on the function call. The files will be added when the zip-object is closed.

Comment: Can you back this up with (reliable) references or a demo?

Comment: @DarkBee See the description of the [`ZipArchive::FL_OPEN_FILE_NOW`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php#ziparchive.constants.fl-open-file-now) flag (wich is not used by default when calling `addFile()`).

Comment: @Olivier I'm not asking for myself, but to give this answer more credibility